# Conditional IF in handlebar.js

Tags: javascript, html, datatables, handlebars.js

I have a dynamic table where data is fetched using Handlebar.js. How to ensure that the table has a max of 3 columns at any given time?I am new to handlebar and can't get my head over how to use a "==" or a ">="  condition in handlebar to check the col number for each dynamically created table. If the number of columns are more than 3; i want to start on a new row.

Please suggest how to proceed with this! all the help is appreciated

```js
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.1/handlebars.min.js"></script>
  
  Handlebars.registerHelper('if_eq', function(a) {
        if (a >= 3) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

```html
 {{#each categories}}
    <table style="border:1px solid black;" id="catlist">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="tblHead" colspan='100%'> <a href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a></td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            {{#each children}}
            <td style="vertical-align:top">
               {{#if children}}
                <a href="{{url}}"> <span class="heading">{{name}} </span></a>
                    <ul>
                        {{#each children}}
                            <a  href="{{url}}"><li>{{name}}</li></a>
                        {{/each}}
                    </ul>
                {{/if}}
            </td>
            {{/each}}
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    {{/each}}
```

Comment: There is no problem using == or >= in handlerbar helper, what you might be in trouble is: where to place the helper.

Comment: "If the number of columns are more than 3; i want to start on a new column." doesn't makes sense. is it new row or new table you want ?

Comment: @BilalSiddiqui Sorry! i need a new row. Just made the edits

Comment: Great, so now can you post data structure ? categories > children > children ? Seems you want rows on categories-children ?

Comment: Yes. Basically I have categories> subcat_lvl1 >subcat_lvl2. Each new subcat_lvl1 should be a new cell in the row. If there are more than 3 subcat_lvl1 for a category: a new row should be created
Overall I need a table with only 3 columns.

Comment: sidenote: `<ul><li><a>...</a></li></ul>` instead of `<ul><a><li>...</li></a></ul>`. The latter is not valid.

Comment: right, thanks Thomas Failed to notice this one

Answer (score 0):

Register a helper for your need, 
 For eg. I create `ifNewRowNeeded` which takes two argument `first` is loop counter and `second` is when to break

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifNewRowNeeded', function(v1, v2, options) {
  if (v1 % v2 == 0) { // will help you creating `tr` on indexes 0, 3, 6, 9 ....
    return options.fn(this);
  }
  return options.inverse(this);
});
```

Now, while iterating just call the helper which will calculate that for you. Like this

```
{{#each children}}
    {{#ifNewRowNeeded @index 3}}
         <tr>
    {{/ifNewRowNeeded}}

     <td>Hello Test</td>

    {{#ifNewRowNeeded @index 3}}
         </tr>
    {{/ifNewRowNeeded}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: I think I am having some issues with registering the new helper. Is there a place where I could learn how to register it? Adding it in a <script> tag does not complete it. I apologise but I am still learning/ trying to figure out how to work with handlebar

Comment: To make helpers work, ensure they are registered before use. so you may put it in HEAD tag and obvious after handlerbars library declared. You may see some tutorials for eg https://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html

Comment: " <script> tag does not complete it" dont know what you are saying here, add a document.ready function as a wrapper and put it inside.  Do not forget to check console for any unexpected error. :) Happy coding :)